# How to vertically align text in tableview header swift

Tags: ios, uitableview, alignment

Here is what I've tried.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    let header = view as? UITableViewHeaderFooterView
    header?.textLabel!.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 25, width: tableView.frame.size.width, height: 50)
    header?.textLabel?.text = "Testing"
    header?.textLabel?.textColor = UIColor.gray
    header?.textLabel?.font = UIFont(name: "Avenir-Book", size: 12)
    return header
}
```

Still to no way to align the text vertically in the section header.

Any ideas?

Comment: can you post a image to see what are you trying and what you have now?

Comment: What I tried didn't move anything. It's still the default header label appearance.

Answer (score 0):

First of all your initialization is wrong, check your value for `header` is always nil, try with this code, you can create your custom header view also, and is better approach

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    let header = UITableViewHeaderFooterView()

        for view in (header.subviews) {
            view.removeFromSuperview()
        }

    let label = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 25, width: tableView.frame.size.width, height: 50))

    label.text = "Testing"
    label.textColor = UIColor.gray
    label.font = UIFont(name: "Avenir-Book", size: 12)
    header.addSubview(label)
    header.bringSubview(toFront: label)
    return header

}
```

I hope this helps you, best regards

Comment: @Reiner Melian.  I just wanted to clarify the purpose of this code in your answer,         for view in (header.subviews) {
            view.removeFromSuperview()
        }       Thanks!

Comment: @joemalski this code removes any previously added UILabel, if you don't do this you get a serie of `UILabel` overlaped, anyway the best approach is create a custom Header View to avoid this